# How to return ListAsync as an object

Tags: c#, list, object, asp.net-core

So currently this method gets the venuetype and outputs it's name, image and cafeID of that venue.

it's currently being returned as an Array, but I want to return it as an object but wasn't sure how to it's a simple question but I've been staring at it for a while now.

```
{
public class VenueTypeResponse
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
   public VenueService(EVouchContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //Gets venuetype and outputs the name, image and cafeID of that venue. 
    public async Task<List<VenueTypeResponse>> GetVenueType()
    {
        return await _context.CafeType.Select(s => new VenueTypeResponse()
        {
            id = s.CafeTypeId,
            Name = s.Name,
            ImageUrl = s.ImageUrl     
        }).ToListAsync();
    }
```

I've tried the approach of removing the  and returning it as .FirstorDefault but it clearly just returns the first venue type and not all of them. Any suggestions would be great! :)

Response I would like

```
{
  data: [ 
    {
      id : 1,
      name : "Take aways",
      imageUrl : "https://..jpg"
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      name : "Desserts",
      imageUrl : "https://..jpg"
    },
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      ...
    }   
  ],
  meta: {
    pageTotal: 1,
    pageCurrent: 1  
  }
}
```

Response I'm getting

```
[
    {
        "name": "Restaurant",
        "imageUrl": "https:..",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Takeaway",
        "imageUrl": "https://...",
        "id": 2
    },
    ...
]
```

Comment: Remove async/await or use `return Task.FromResult(await ... )`

Comment: Could you show an example of the response you want to have?

Comment: @Tseng If I remove async/await do I have to remove the .ToListAsync as well?

Comment: @juunas will add it in now

Comment: You want to get `List<VenueTypeResponse>` instead of `Task<List<VenueTypeResponse>>`?

Comment: @GuruStron What's the difference between the two?

Comment: You need to create an class which will contain the all needed properties and assign result of you query to the `data` one.

Comment: A List is an Object, what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: it's current being outputted as an array

Comment: The question is what you *want* it to look like. Can you give an example of the json you want? It's not clear how you intend to make a list/array be returned as an object.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i've mentioned it above

Comment: It's being output as what looks like json (JavaScript Object Notation), json is just a string format designed to be used as a data interchange format not for presenting/ printing data. Also json doesn't have lists, only arrays, but they act like JS arrays in that they are dynamic and basically equal to a List in C#

Comment: Create a wrapper object with the `Data` property holding the list, is that what you want?

Comment: return Task<V2JsonResponse<List<VenueTypeResponse>>>>  where V2JsonResponse is our own data structure to cause the json serialiser to return data inside of the json object { data : ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an object that holds your list, something like this:

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<VenueTypeResponse> Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("meta")]
    public ResponseMeta Meta { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseMeta
{
    [JsonProperty("pageTotal")]
    public int PageTotal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pageCurrent")]
    public int PageCurrent { get; set; }
}
```

and then either return this from your method, or wrap the result from this method into this object, before returning it from your endpoint.

Comment: Where would I store the, image url, name and Id?

Comment: would I return it like this? Task<Response<List<VenueTypeResponse>>>

Comment: No, just `Task<Response>`, the Response class is not generic, it has a property with the list, the Data property, you need to set it to refer to the list instance.